# WordPress admin-ajax.php returns 0

Tags: wordpress, jquery

Are currently developing a plugin that need ajax. Was thinking of doing it "correctly", so am trying to use admin-ajax.php. However I always get 0 as response, and somehow get the feeling that it never gets to my callback.

Here's the code, have tried to keep simple.

**Load js and setting admin-ajax.php outside admin**

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-more-posts-ajax', SE_WP_MY_PLUGIN_URI . '/js/more-posts-ajax.js?' . rand(), array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script('my-more-posts-ajax', 'MyAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

**Actions for callback**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_more_posts', array($this, 'load_more_posts_callback'));
add_action('wp_ajax_my_more_posts', array($this, 'load_more_posts_callback'));
```

**PHP callback function**

```
public function load_more_posts_callback() {
$response = json_encode(array('success' => TRUE));

header("Content-Type: application/json");
print $response;

exit;
}
```

**js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#my-show-more-form').submit(function(event) {
    /* Prevent submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = {
      action: 'my_more_posts',
      offset: 8
    };

    jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
      alert('Response: ' + response);
    });
  });
});
```

Anyone got any ideas of what is wrong? Think I got all code for this.

Comment: Got it to work, well, kind of anyway.

I tested to move things around a bit, and when I put actions wp_ajax... directly in plugin file, instead of calling inside class.

Answer (score -1):

use `wp_die();` instead of `exit;` inside PHP callback function.

So this will be

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print $response;
wp_die();
```